# Ubuntu 16.04: Turn off new feature that external storage/trash now display number of windows open

Tags: nautilus, launcher, 16.04

One of the new features of 16.04 is that if one opens the trash or an external hard drive, then it has a separate icon in the launcher instead of the usual Nautilus icon. I personally find this very annoying and was wondering if there is any way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

I also find this annoying as I keep all my data on an NTFS partition which I auto mount.

The only workaround I found for this is to make links to the folders I use (the ones located on the external partition) and then move the links to your Home location.